# Do twin-blade circular saws reduce tearout?

Tags: saw, circular-saw

Do twin-blade / Twincutter circular saws produce a more accurate cut than regular circular saws? Do they have less kick-back? Do they reduce the tearout / splintering / chipping at the rear of the cut, compared to regular, single-blade circular saws? I'm looking for real-world experience, as I've seen countless sales-pitches on the matter.

The Twin-Cutter circular saws have two circular saw-blades spinning in opposite directions. It behaves similar to a regular circular saw, except with a slightly wider kerf (since there are two blades), with aparent benefits. Here is a [sales pitch video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTnMrW1dOEI) on YouTube

Some additional articles which I find inconclusive:

- [Genius or Junk? The Dual Saw](http://toolmonger.com/2011/11/07/genius-or-junk-the-dual-saw)
- [Twin-Blade Circular Saws](http://www.toolselect.com/browse/single-category/Twin-Blade-Circular-Saws0)

Comment: More waste as sawdust would be the general rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the real place where this tool is useful compared to a traditional circular saw is for plunge cuts. I can't imagine where this would outperform a regular circular saw for a non-plunge cut unless you had tight access that a smaller twin blade could get into.

Answer (score 2):

I purchased one of these dual blade circular saws and to be honest they are no better than the persons talents using any power tools. Save your cash to buy the best quality saw that will give you the ability to do anything you want. My best investment to date in circular saws was my worm drive. It is heavier than others and needs more room but it doesn't kick back and has the power to cut anything I put in her path.Everyone has to try everything themselves so try to find someone who owns one and will let you try it out, plunge cutting is their major asset but this is no problem with my worm drive either  ;) :)

Answer (score 0):

Regular circular saw works just fine if you know how to use it. There are also smaller 4.5" circular saws that may be better for intricate work like flooring or someone with less strength. The trick is to put the shoe down before you put the blade down so that it doesn't kick. Having a laser guide on the saw can also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, most of the benefits they tried to ascribe to this new technology are not unique to it, you can do most of that with a standard circular saw. The only thing I saw different, and it might be nice IF you need to do that a lot, is the plunge cut going backward. You can plunge cut with a standard circular saw, but going backward is a bit tricky, running a risk of the saw jumping out of the kerf.

Having to deal with the wax lube stick negates that single benefit as far as I'm concerned.